# Capacitor cannot open Android Studio

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to convert a react app to a mobile version. When I run npx cap open android I get the following error:

[error] Unable to launch Android Studio. Is it installed?
Attempted to open Android Studio at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe
You can configure this with the CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH` as a Windows environment variable with the path where your Android Studio (studio64.exe) is installed as it's value.

Then restart your PC.

This worked to me.

Good luck!